# Add predefined offline pack to the react-native-mapbox-gl

Tags: android, react-native, offline, mapbox-gl

As you can see in the [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/API.md#offline)
documentation we can add some offline pack to the app. 
With this approach, the user must be connected to the internet and get the defined bounds and save them on the device.

I'm looking for a way that can save some bounds data in the app bundle and mapbox get the data from that so the user can access defined bounds without the internet connection. 
Is there any way?

Comment: Hi! Any solution?

Comment: @Yonedev Hi. Unfortunately no :\